# asp.net with javascript page refresh

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.Net appl composed by three pages; page1, page2 and page3
The execution starts on page one. Page1 calls Page2, but page1 has to be visible still, so user can still work on that page. When Page2 closes, a java script function calls Page3, so all the cleaning is done on page 3. When page 3 completes its task, the window goes, and only Page1 is displayed
To call page3 from page two I use something like this;

```
xHRObject.open("GET", "Default3.aspx?SiEditor=E&idSec=N&F="+idenValue, false);
```

The problem is the following:
the info updated on page 2, has to be updated on page1, but it does not. If I place I similar java script on page3 to call page1, it instantiates a new page, rather than refreshing the current one. How do I access page1? If we use modal forms for page2, the control goes back to page1 with no problems, but I can not use modals in this case

Any idea how to refresh page1 when page2 and 3 are disposed?

Comment: do these pages display in the same window or are they opened in separate windows?

Comment: they are opened in separate windows

Answer (score 0):

When you create new windows you can access the window that opened them via the [opener](http://w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_win_opener.asp) property. You can then use the location object to reload the page.

So this could be the body tag on your page 2:

```
<body onunload="window.opener.location.reload([true])">
```